# Installing Docker On Ubuntu App For Windows

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install docker on ubuntu app provided by windows app store.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

[image]

this works with force ssl command

```
curl -4fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

But when adding respository

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

It again throws error for unable to resolve the host

[image]

Please suggest a resolution to solve this dns resolving issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check whether u have docker or not, by any chance u might install:

```
$docker --version
```

then, remove old version

```
$sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

try to install particular Docker version(this shows available links):

```
$apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

choose particular version:

```
$sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION_STRING> docker-ce-cli=<VERSION_STRING> containerd.io
$sudo apt-get update
```

check whether installation was successful or not:

```
$sudo docker run hello-world
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: These works on normal ubuntu machine..

Windows 10 has introduce embeded ubuntu machine for windows.
`https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab`

Problem is something relating to limited access to networking feature in embeded OS.